# CocoaAsyncSocket uploading issue (upload to FTP Server , always lost part of my data)

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, cocoaasyncsocket

My ios app is using GCDAsyncSocket to communicate with my FTP Server,however when I try to upload some files to the server,it is very likely to lose a couple of bytes.

Below is the general idea of my code :

```
var bytesWritten : Int64 = 0

func prepareForUpload(){
   self.uploadSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate:self,delegateQueue:GLOBAL_QUEUE_DEFAULT);

   self.fileStream = NSInputStream(fileAtPath:FILE_PATH);
   self.fileStream.open();
}

func uploadRemainningFile(){
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0)){
    var readBuffer = [UInt8](count:32768,repeatedValue:0);
    let bytesRead = self.readStream(&readBuffer,32768);

    if(bytesRead>0){
       let dataToWrite = NSData(bytes:&readBuffer,length:bytesRead);
       self.uploadSocket.writeData(dataToWrite,withTimeout:-1,tag:WRITE_TAG);
       bytesWritten += bytesRead;
       self.uploadSocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1,tag:WRITE_TAG);
    }
  }

}
```

and in the GCDAsyncSocket delegate method:

```
func socket(sock:GCDAsyncSocket!,didWriteDataWithTag tag:Int){
   if tag == WRITE_TAG{
     if(bytesWritten>=FILE_SIZE){
        self.uploadSocket.disconnect();
     }
     else{
        self.uploadRemainningFile();
     }
   }

}
```

Since the documentation of GCDAsyncSocket said that the delegate method  `socket(sock:GCDAsyncSocket!,didWriteDataWithTag tag:Int)`  will be called when a socket has COMPLETED writing the requested data,and will not be called if an error occurs,So i think my code would work like:

I first invoke `uploadRemainningFile()` to read the first part of my file,
then inside `uploadRemainningFile()` invokes `writeData()`,which will later invoke its delegate method `socket(didWriteDataWithTag)`,then inside the delegate method , if the file hasn't reach its end, the delegate method invokes `uploadRemainningFile()` again but this time `uploadRemainningFile()` reads the second part of my file ,and this should loop until the file reaches its end.

Sometimes the code above works fine and sometimes doesn't,and a couple of bytes of my file went missing.

I thought it was because i disconnect the uploadSocket too quickly,so i changed `disconnect()` to `disconnectAfterWriting()`,but it's not working,and in both case i am getting no error.

Could anyone help me with this ?